# mv command: moving only certain extension files, not having a string in their name

Tags: command-line, mv

I am trying to incorporate 'mv' command in a dockerfile.

I want to move only those files having certain extension, but not having a string in their name.

Suppose src directory has abc.txt, abcu.txt, def.xml, 1abc2.txt, mno.txt, pqr.txt and I want to move only .txt files and not having 'abc' in their name. So only mno.txt and pqr.txt are to be moved.

What would be the optimum way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With extended shell globbing:

```
$ ls *.txt
1abc2.txt  abc.txt  abcu.txt  mno.txt  pqr.txt
$
# Enable extended shell globbing
$ shopt -s extglob
$
# "echo" is for a dry-run
$ echo mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- !(*abc*).txt
mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- mno.txt pqr.txt
$
# Disable extended shell globbing
$ shopt -u extglob
```

With `find`:

```
$ find ! -name "*abc*" -name "*.txt" -exec echo mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- {} +
mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- ./mno.txt ./pqr.txt
```

**Notices**:

1. `echo` is added in front of `mv` in the above two examples for a safe dry-run ... You need to remove it when satisfied with the output so the actual moving will happen.
2. The `-t` option of `mv` specifies the target/destination directory and it expects an argument after it in the form of a path like `-t /path/to/dest`.
3. If you need to specify the path to the source directory containing the files in the first example, then it needs to be after `--` and directly before the glob pattern like `mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- /path/to/source/!(*abc*).txt` … While in the second example, it can be done like this `find /path/to/source/ ! -name "*abc*" -name "*.txt" -exec echo mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- {} +`.
4. The first example with shell globbing after the `mv` command is subject to system’s maximum arguments length/size allowed for a command and while that should be fairly large on Ubuntu (*Last I checked, it was around 2 MB*) but you need to know that anyway … The second example with `find`, however, is not affected by this restriction.

Comment: 'mv -nv -t -t /path/to/dest -- mno.txt pqr.txt'....do I need to mention files I need to move.

Comment: No, that's the output of the command `echo` in the demonstration above ... Your files will be matched by the glob patterns automatically. ... and sorry for the typo double `-t -t` will fix it now ... You'll basically need to run `mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- !(*abc*).txt` after you try the demonstration with `echo` first to see a dry-run of the actual files that will be moved first for safety.

Comment: Got it. And if I am not inside source directory, I would need to add path to it before path/to/dest.

Comment: 'mv -nv -t a/b/lib ${MY_HOME}/lib/ -- !(*jetty*).nar'...this would all .nar files not having jetty in thier name, from a/b/lib to ${MY_HOME}/lib/ .

Comment: You'll need to add path to source files if you are not in the source directory, but after `--` and directly before the glob pattern e.g.  `mv -nv -t /path/to/dest -- /path/to/source/!(*abc*).txt`

Comment: No, `!(jetty).nar'` will only exclude the one file with the exact name `jetty.nar` and include any other file with extension `.nar`... You'll need a pattern like `!(*jetty*).nar'` ... And No, `-t /path/to/dest` is the destination directory.